# PHP Regex specify multiple paths using glob()

Tags: php, regex, directory, glob

```
glob("aaafolder/*php")
glob("bbbfolder/*php")
glob("cccfolder/*php")
```

Is it possible to simplify this?

```
glob("(?=aaafolder/*php)(?=bbbfolder/*php)(?=cccfolder/*php)")
```

The above returns nothing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[**This note**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#103022) on the manual page of **`glob()`** seems to answer your question, saying that glob is not limited to a single directory : using **`GLOB_BRACE`**, you can specify several directories.

I'm quoting the example that `@Ultimater` gives there :

```
$results=glob("{includes/*.php,core/*.php}",GLOB_BRACE);
```

<sub>User-notes on the manual pages often contain useful informations and examples ;-)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As the [PHP manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) said, its the `GLOB_BRACE` flag.

```
glob("{aaafolder/*php,bbbfolder/*php,cccfolder/*php}", GLOB_BRACE)
```