# PHP: Using glob() to list *.txt and directories?

Tags: php, regex

Instead of listing all the files and directories

```
foreach(glob("/*") as $file) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to filter *.txt files and directories? Because with this example

```
foreach(glob("/*.txt") as $file) {
    ...
}
```

Will only get the *.txt files, but not the directories. But to list only directories, this will work:

```
foreach(glob("/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $file) {
    ...
}
```

but will left out the *.txt files. I am trying to avoid using preg_match() or similar operations post reading the directory because it will waste server resources if there are around 5000 unnecessary files (image files with *.jpg, *.png).

Thank you.

Comment: Why not call `glob()` twice and combine the resulting arrays before parsing?

Comment: Yes, that can be an option. But wondering if it's possible in one go. Thanks!

Comment: @user702300 How would you make the difference between a file named `foo` and a directory named `foo`. I think you need to use two functions, one to get all directories and the other one to get specific files.

Comment: This might be helpful: [PHP Regex specify multiple paths using glob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663974/php-regex-specify-multiple-paths-using-glob)

Comment: @HamZa For files, I am only interested in *.txt, for directly, any name, thanks!

Comment: @showdev Using Regex means I have to first scan all the files and directories first, that's not what I want. Let's say if I have 100 *.txt files and 10 directories, but has other file types like *.png, *.jpg with 5000 files, then I am wasting resources a lot if this operation has to be performed often.

Comment: @user702300 I think you didn't get what I meant ... To get only directories, you would need to use `*` with `GLOB_ONLYDIR`. But, if `GLOB_ONLYDIR` is set, you can't match `*.txt`. Now let's say you don't use `GLOB_ONLYDIR`, how can you identify a folder by just it's name ? Impossible.

Comment: @user702300 Despite the title, the answers there use `GLOB_BRACE` to specify multiple paths (not regex).

Comment: @showdev I think GLOB_BRACE might be the answer like you've mentioned. Do you know how I can do that to specify the current directory and the subdirectory one level below? I can't seem to find an example for this, the only one I've found was: $results=glob("{includes/*.php,core/*.php}",GLOB_BRACE);

Comment: @user702300: `glob()` function **always** scans the whole directory...

Answer (score 1):

Also tried GLOB_BRACE, but it didn't work, so had to use the following code:

```
$aDir1 = glob('/*.txt');   // current directory
$aDir2 = glob('/*/*.txt'); // subdirectory, one level below

$aDir = asort(array_merge($aDir1, $aDir2));
```

Thank you.