# Delete files from multiple folders

Tags: php, syntax

I have a simple PHP script that delete files from one foler and it looks like this:

```
$files = glob('all/*'); 
foreach($files as $file){ 
if(is_file($file))
unlink($file);
```

I have two other folders "added" and "old" and I want to delete files in these folders too, how can I do this?

I tried this

```
$files = glob('all/*,added/*,old/*');
```

and this

```
$files = glob('all/*','added/*','old/*');
```

but it's not working.

Comment: You may find [the official document of `glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) helpful, especially its [highest rated comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#88250).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array('all/*','added/*','old/*');
foreach ($arr as $a) {
$files = glob($a); 
foreach($files as $file){ 
if(is_file($file))
unlink($file); 
}
}
```

also a more direct approach can be found here [PHP Regex specify multiple paths using glob()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663974/php-regex-specify-multiple-paths-using-glob)

Comment: for a more direct approach though try GLOB_BRACE as in the example of the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$folders = [ 'all/*', 'added/*', 'old/*' ];

foreach($folders as $folder) {
    $files = glob($folder); 
    foreach($files as $file){ 
        if(is_file($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```